# RadListBox DragDropBehavior Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, drag-and-drop, radlistbox

I'm trying to use binding in DragDropBehavior of RadListBox like this

```
    <UserControl xmlns:telerik="http://schemas.telerik.com/2008/xaml/presentation"  x:Class="MyProject.Views.MyView"
                 ....
                 xmlns:behaviors="clr-namespace:MyProject.Behaviors"
                 mc:Ignorable="d"
                 d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
   <Grid>
        ...
        <telerik:RadListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
                    <telerik:RadListBox.DragDropBehavior>
                        <behaviors:MyDragDropBehavior AllowReorder="True" DropCommand="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=DataContext.DropCommand}"/>
                    </telerik:RadListBox.DragDropBehavior>
        </telerik:RadListBox>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

View gets viewmodel via injection

```
public partial class MyView : UserControl 
    {
        public MyView (ViewModels.MyViewModel viewModel)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = viewModel;
        }
    }
```

Behaviour code:

```
public class MyDragDropBehavior : Telerik.Windows.DragDrop.Behaviors.ListBoxDragDropBehavior
    {
        public override bool CanDrop(Telerik.Windows.DragDrop.Behaviors.DragDropState state)
        {
            return state.IsSameControl;
        }

        public override void Drop(Telerik.Windows.DragDrop.Behaviors.DragDropState state)
        {
            base.Drop(state);
            DropCommand.Execute(null);
        }

        public ICommand DropCommand
        {
            get { return (ICommand)GetValue(DropCommandProperty); }
            set { SetValue(DropCommandProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty DropCommandProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("DropCommand", typeof(ICommand), typeof(MyDragDropBehavior), new PropertyMetadata(null));
    }
```

Items binding is working well. Behavior is working but binding to DropCommand is not. I obtain binding error:

*Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='System.Windows.Controls.UserControl', AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:Path=DataContext.DropCommand; DataItem=null; target element is 'MyDragDropBehavior' (HashCode=25707777); target property is 'DropCommand' (type 'ICommand')*

ViewModel is

```
public class MyViewModel
    {
        public MyViewModel()
        {
            DropCommand = new DelegateCommand(OnDrop);
            Items = new ObservableCollection<MyItem>();
        }

        public ObservableCollection<MyItem> Items { get; set; }

        public DelegateCommand DropCommand { get; set; }

        private void OnDrop()
        {

        }
    }
```

What is wrong?

I have found a way to solve the issue by following

```
<telerik:RadListBox DragDropBehavior="{Binding DragDropBehavior}">
```

But I still don't understand why previous method doesn't work. I'll appreciate if somebody knows.

Comment: There are a few missing information in your question to answer correctly. Find Ancestor is not done correctly. You need to say what is UserControl bound to and the viewmodel misses the corresponding property for  `{Binding Items}`. So please give the entire structure.

Comment: There is a lot of code. I'm just trying to reduce it. Everything is working except binding in behaviour

Comment: True, but its not possible to findout the problem with the above provided code as its missing key information pointed out in the previous comment.

Comment: I've just added some code to the post. What kind of information I need to provide? I'm not sure that I clearly understand you.